# Web scraping table filtering results

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm using Python to Web Scrape a table of data found [here](https://web.ashevillechamber.org/cwt/external/wcpages/wcdirectory/Directory.aspx?CategoryID=1242&Title=Accounting++and++Bookkeeping&AdKeyword=Accounting++and++Bookkeeping).  Specifically, I want to pull the business name, url, owners name, street, city, and phone.  After being run through Beautiful Soup and split the code to filter appears as:

> 

['\\\', \\\' href="?listingid=9758&profileid=217Y3Q544Y&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2f**www.jpspa.com**" target="_BLANK"', "**Johnson Price Sprinkle PA**', '/a", "', '/b", "', '/td", "', '/tr", "', '/table", "', '/td", "', '/tr", '', 'tr class="GeneralBody"', '', 'td bgcolor="#808080" height="1"', '', 'img border="0" height="1" src="images/dot_clear.gif" width="1"/', "', '/td", "', '/tr", "', '/table", "', '/td", "', '/tr", '', 'tr class="GeneralBody"', '', 'td align="left" valign="top" width="90%"', '**Maria Pilos**', "', '', '**79 Woodfin Place, Suite 300**", "', '', '**Asheville, NC  28801**", "', '', '", 'b', "Phone:', '/b", ' ****(828) 254-2374****', "', '', '", 'b', "Fax:', '/b", " (828) 252-9994', '\', \'", '\\\', \\\' href="DirectoryEmailForm.aspx?listingid=9758"', "Send Email', '/a", "', '/td", '', 'td align="right" rowspan="3" valign="top" width="10%"', '', 'span style="font-size: 8pt"', '\\\', \\\' href="?, '!--..End Listing--", '', "/td']<

I bolded the values I want to return and I identified their position in the code.  To filter them the code is below.  Temp_array is the code above to filter, temp_count is the position in the array, and business_listing is the array I'm appending the value to when found.  Basically when the temp_count == the position of the value in the array, it appends that value to the array.

```
        <
        temp_count=0
            for i in temp_array:
                if temp_count ==0:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1
                elif temp_count ==2:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1
                elif temp_count ==19:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1    
                elif temp_count ==19:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1
                elif temp_count ==20:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1
                elif temp_count ==23:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1
                elif temp_count ==27:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1
                elif temp_count ==42:
                    business_listings.append(i)
                    temp_count+=1
                    
        else:
            count+=1
```

> 

The output is as follows:
['\\\', \\\' href="?listingid=9758&profileid=2B713K5Z48&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.jpspa.com" target="_BLANK"']>
and only filters the first 2 values or won't filter anything.

Answer (score 0):

This script will print information about various businesses:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://web.ashevillechamber.org/cwt/external/wcpages/wcdirectory/Directory.aspx?CategoryID=1242&Title=Accounting++and++Bookkeeping&AdKeyword=Accounting++and++Bookkeeping'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')


for b in soup.select('td[bgcolor="#E6E6E6"] b'):
    business_name = b.text
    business_url = b.a['href'] if b.a else '-'
    owner = b.find_next('td', width="90%").contents[0]

    addr, current = [], owner.find_next(text=True)
    while not current.find_parent('b'):
        addr.append(current.strip())
        current = current.find_next(text=True)

    addr = '\n'.join(addr)
    phone = current.find_next(text=True).strip()

    print('Business Name :', business_name)
    print('Business URL  :', business_url)
    print('Owner         :', owner)
    print('Phone         :', phone)
    print('Address:')
    print(addr)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Business Name : Johnson Price Sprinkle PA
Business URL  : ?listingid=9758&profileid=2D7R3B5E4N&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.jpspa.com
Owner         : Maria Pilos
Phone         : (828) 254-2374
Address:
79 Woodfin Place, Suite 300
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Leah B. Noel, CPA, PC
Business URL  : ?listingid=9656&profileid=549S620J3J&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.lbnoelcpa.com%2f
Owner         : Ms. Leah Noel
Phone         : 828-333-4529
Address:
14 S. Pack Square #503
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Worley, Woodbery, & Associates, PA
Business URL  : ?listingid=9661&profileid=3L7R304J8X&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.worleycpa.com%2f
Owner         : Mr. David Worley
Phone         : (828) 271-7997
Address:
7 Orchard Street, Ste. 202
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Peridot Consulting, Inc.
Business URL  : ?listingid=14005&profileid=7L724E5W7E&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.PeridotConsultingInc.com
Owner         : John Michael  Kledis
Phone         : (828) 242-6971
Address:
PO Box 8904
Asheville, NC  28804
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : DHG
Business URL  : ?listingid=9579&profileid=25711D625I&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.dhgllp.com%2f
Owner         : Adrienne Bernardi
Phone         : (828) 254-2254
Address:
PO Box 3049
Asheville, NC  28802
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Gould Killian CPA Group, P.A.
Business URL  : ?listingid=9659&profileid=2P7X216Y66&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.gk-cpa.com
Owner         : Ed Towson
Phone         : (828) 258-0363
Address:
100 Coxe Avenue
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Michelle Tracz CPA, CFE, PLLC
Business URL  : ?listingid=12921&profileid=610C8H3I7N&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.michelletraczcpa.com
Owner         : Michelle Tracz
Phone         : (828) 280-2530
Address:
1238 Hendersonville Rd.
Asheville, NC  28803
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Burleson & Earley, P.A.
Business URL  : ?listingid=10436&profileid=57132N5P9C&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.burlesonearley.com%2f
Owner         : Bronwyn Burleson, CPA
Phone         : (828) 251-2846
Address:
902 Sand Hill Road
Asheville, NC  28806
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Carol L. King & Associates, P.A.
Business URL  : ?listingid=10439&profileid=2Z8C7I0B4X&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.clkcpa.com
Owner         : Carol King
Phone         : (828) 258-2323
Address:
40 North French Broad Avenue
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Goldsmith Molis & Gray
Business URL  : ?listingid=12638&profileid=6C8D2C7F55&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.gmg-cpa.com
Owner         : Allen Gray
Phone         : (828) 281-3161
Address:
32 Orange St.
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Corliss & Solomon, PLLC
Business URL  : ?listingid=12407&profileid=6T7Y798S1R&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.candspllc.com
Owner         : Slater Solomon
Phone         : (828) 236-0206
Address:
242 Charlotte St., Suite 1
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Mountain BizWorks
Business URL  : ?listingid=12733&profileid=2L9E9G6A1S&action=uweb&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.mountainbizworks.org
Owner         : Matthew Raker
Phone         : (828) 253-2834
Address:
153 South Lexington Ave.
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : LeBlanc CPA Limited
Business URL  : -
Owner         : Leslie LeBlanc
Phone         : (828) 225-4940
Address:
218 Broadway
Asheville, NC  28801-2347
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Bolick & Associates, PA, CPA's
Business URL  : -
Owner         : Alan E Bolick, CPA
Phone         : (828) 253-4692
Address:
Central Office Park   Suite 104
56 Central Avenue
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

EDIT: To parse URLs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import unquote


url = 'https://web.ashevillechamber.org/cwt/external/wcpages/wcdirectory/Directory.aspx?CategoryID=1242&Title=Accounting++and++Bookkeeping&AdKeyword=Accounting++and++Bookkeeping'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')


for b in soup.select('td[bgcolor="#E6E6E6"] b'):
    business_name = b.text
    business_url = b.a['href'] if b.a else '-'
    owner = b.find_next('td', width="90%").contents[0]

    addr, current = [], owner.find_next(text=True)
    while not current.find_parent('b'):
        addr.append(current.strip())
        current = current.find_next(text=True)

    addr = '\n'.join(addr)
    phone = current.find_next(text=True).strip()

    print('Business Name :', business_name)
    print('Business URL  :', unquote(business_url).rsplit('=', maxsplit=1)[-1])
    print('Owner         :', owner)
    print('Phone         :', phone)
    print('Address:')
    print(addr)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Business Name : Johnson Price Sprinkle PA
Business URL  : http://www.jpspa.com
Owner         : Maria Pilos
Phone         : (828) 254-2374
Address:
79 Woodfin Place, Suite 300
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Business Name : Leah B. Noel, CPA, PC
Business URL  : http://www.lbnoelcpa.com/
Owner         : Ms. Leah Noel
Phone         : 828-333-4529
Address:
14 S. Pack Square #503
Asheville, NC  28801
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help,  this is far more efficient than what I had.  Just a follow-up question; how would you filter the URL so just the web address remains?  again thanks

Comment: @NickPicciano I don't understand...do you want to store just the URL? Then you can append `business_url` to the list.

Comment: I want to remove the extraneous characters from business_url, everything from the ? to ‘www’ so all that remains is ‘www.the_business_website’.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm trying to learn as much as I can and was curious about the first line; for b in soup.select('td[bgcolor="#E6E6E6"] b') . My interpretation of this is it selects the 'td' tag from 'bgcolor="#E6E6E6" to tag 'b'.  Is that correct?

Comment: @NickPicciano it's CSS selector. It will select all `<b>` tags that are under `<td>` tags with `bgcolor="E6E6E6"`